# launcher.sh behaves differently @reboot than calling with sh

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, boot

I am using a launcher.sh for a raspberrypi 4B with Raspi os x64 to start a python script in a python env on startup. But setting the environment is problematic.

The file (test.sh) looks like:

```
. envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

or alternatively

```
#!bin/bash
. envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

**using `sh test.sh`, correctly executes the shell script.**
However, using it at launch with crontab

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/test.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

I get an error:

> /home/pi/test.sh: 2: .: cannot open envname/bin/activate: No such file

**How to properly set source `@reboot` to start the env on startup?**

p.s. sh is not the solution.
With `bin/sh` and `source envname/bin/activate` it does not work as Ubuntu apparently uses bash rather than sh, and if sh is used the source command is not known. Bash uses `.` instead of `source`

Edit 1:
Normal Ubuntu uses bash for shell, but maybe that is different on startup? Could that be a way?

Comment: for this kind of question consider https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: But I think, it is actually a Ubuntu question and in combination with python environment. So kind of suiting here, or not? But I will also try there. Thanks

Comment: then we also have https://askubuntu.com (or https://unix.stackexchange.com/). I don't know which is more appropriate, but StackOverflow is generally more for software development than OS stuff. Just avoid crossposting!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Goldilocks](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/5538/goldilocks) [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/138578/launcher-sh-behaves-differently-reboot-than-calling-with-sh/138580#138580) tell us that the path has to be absolute, as crontab does not know where to find envname.

`find | grep envname` returned that it is at `/home/pi/envname`

so:

```
#!bin/bash
. /home/pi/envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

does work.